# Symfony2 timezone with form

Tags: forms, symfony, timezone

I'm trying to deal with timezone in form.

My date is stored in UTC.
I want that the form convert this date in a timezone (Europe/Paris) and when a user 
enter the date, date are convert back in utc in database.

Here is my form:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\MyBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;

/**
 * Broadcasting form without broadcast choice
 */
class BroadcastingEditType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        var_dump(get_class($builder));
        $builder
            ->add('id_broadcasting', 'genemu_plain',
                array('label'=>'Id')
            )
            ->add('start_time', 'datetime',
                array(
                    'label'          => 'Début',
                    'required'       => true,
                    'date_widget'    => 'single_text',
                    'time_widget'    => 'choice',
                    'model_timezone' => 'UTC',
                    'view_timezone'  => 'Europe/Paris',
                    'attr'           => array('class' => 'input')
                )
            );
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            array(
               'data_class' => 'Edd\VavBundle\Entity\Broadcasting',
                'view_timezone'     => 'UTC',
            )
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'acme_mybundle_broadacasting_type';
    }
}
```

I've tried other values for options model_timezone and view_timezone, but date
value remain in UTC instead of Europe/Paris.

my default timezone is Europe/Paris.

What I missed?.

Answer (score 0):

It may come from the `setDefaultOptions`, there, the `view_timezone` is set to `'UTC'`...

Could that be the problem ?